# Sometimes code is executing perfectly but at other times, the same code is not executing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While automating, sometimes code is executing perfectly but at other times, the same code is not executing.

I have given specific time Thread.sleep and sometimes i have given implicit wait and webDriverWait also given. I have worked on 3 types but sometimes code is not executing. 
error;
sometimes element is not found and 
sometimes error is element not visible

> Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[text()='Send']} at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Nativ‌​e
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknow‌​n
>   Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Un‌​known
>   Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(Erro‌​rHandler.java:215)

what could be the solution for it.

Comment: Could you paste in some of your error code into your question ... it would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[text()='Send']}
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what the page looks liken you are getting failures? Its possible that you are not even on the page you thought you were if trying to log in and it failed or something. If an element is not visible then you need to figure out why. Do you need to scroll or click on something? Try manually walking through what you think the automation is doing and see if you can locate a slow page load or element not being visible.